# PHP trim and space not working

Tags: php, encoding, space, trim

I have some data imported from a csv. The import script grabs all email addresses in the csv and after validating them, imports them into a db.

A client has supplied this csv, and some of the emails seem to have a space at the end of the cell. No problem, trim that sucker off... nope, wont work.

The space seems to not be a space, and isn't being removed so is failing a bunch of the emails validation.

**Question:** Any way I can actually detect what this erroneous character is, and how I can remove it?

Not sure if its some funky encoding, or something else going on, but I dont fancy going through and removing them all manually! If I UTF-8 encode the string first it shows this character as a:

> Â

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump(ord(substr($email, -1)));` and then passing that character (using `\xHEX` syntax) to `trim()`?

Comment: there is such a thing called `Ideographic Space` also

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If that "space" is not affected by `trim()`, the first step is to identify it.

Use `urlencode()` on the string. Urlencode will percent-escape any non-printable and a lot of printable characters besides ASCII, so you will see the hexcode of the offending characters instantly. Depending on what you discover, you can act accordingly or update your question to get additional help.

Comment: okay so its coming out as %A0 after a urlencode, which is an nbsp, which should get trimmed right? but isnt :(

Comment: The non breaking space is not on the list of characters that get trimmed. If you want it removed, you have to add it to the list of characters yourself. See the documentation of trim: http://de1.php.net/trim

Comment: I didn't know how to add the non-breaking space to the list of characters, I tried `trim($value, urlencode("%A0"))` and it worked

Comment: That should probably read `urldecode("%A0")`, as it is the inverse. PHP allows to directly add bytes to strings with the escape sequence `\x`, so this string would be `"\xA0"` here: `trim($value, "\xA0")`. And there is the `chr()` function accepting an integer value that does the same: `trim($value, chr(0xA0)`. `0xA0` is the hex writing for an integer, much like `160` is it's decimal writing. Note that this simply adds the byte, and does not respect any charset encoding.

Answer (score 9):

Replace all UTF-8 spaces with standard spaces and then do the trim!

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s/u', ' ', $string);
echo trim($string)
```

This is it.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, also loading emails from CSVs and having issues with "undetectable" whitespaces.

Resolved it by replacing the most common urlencoded whitespace chars with ''. This might help if can't use mb_detect_encoding() and/or iconv()

```
    $urlEncodedWhiteSpaceChars   = '%81,%7F,%C5%8D,%8D,%8F,%C2%90,%C2,%90,%9D,%C2%A0,%A0,%C2%AD,%AD,%08,%09,%0A,%0D';
    $temp = explode(',', $urlEncodedWhiteSpaceChars); // turn them into a temp array so we can loop accross
    $email_address  = urlencode($row['EMAIL_ADDRESS']);
        foreach($temp as $v){
            $email_address  =  str_replace($v, '', $email_address);     // replace the current char with nuffink
        }
        $email_address = urldecode($email_address); // undo the url_encode
```

Note that this does NOT strip the 'normal' space character and that it removes these whitespace chars from anywhere in the string - not just start or end.

Answer (score 1):

In most of the cases a simple `strip_tags($string)` will work.

If the above doesn't work, then you should try to identify the characters resorting to `urlencode()` and then act accordingly.

Comment: `strip_tags()` will never remove whitespace.

Comment: In this scenario Trim() is not working! So using strip_tags() solves this particularly strange problem.

Answer (score 0):

I see couples of possible solutions

1) Get last char of string in PHP and check if it is a normal character (with regexp for example). If it is not a normal character, then remove it.

```
$length = strlen($string);
$string[($length-1)] = '';
```

2) Convert your character from UTF-8 to encoding of you CSV file and use str_replace. For example if you CSV is encoded in ISO-8859-2

```
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-2', "Â");
```

Comment: It seems to be an encoding issue. You should get the hold on what char it is. otherwhise you might get other errors to. Remember to be consequent in usage of encoding. For the database, etc.